# Language options in Dynasty Warriors Gundam 3 (European 360 version)

Tags: xbox-360, dynasty-warriors

Are there options for language audio in the European version of Dynasty Warriors Gundam 3 for Xbox 360?

English dub only? Japanese with English subtitles? Options for either? DLC language packs?

As far as I know the first game had both language options, and the second was dub-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can change spoken language from English to Japanese in the Xbox 360 version, but not on starting the game - only after the first mission.

Answer (score 1):

Language Options were included in the ps3 version, so I'm positive it will also be in the Xbox version.

It is no dlc by the way.